# XML почему появляется мусор в добавленных нодах?

Tags: c#, xml

```
XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
doc1.Load(filePath1);
```

Документ вида:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DBModel xmlns="http://tempuri.org/DBModel.xsd">
  <Persons>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>TestName</Name>
    <SecondName>TestSecName</SecondName>
    <ThirdName>TestThirdName</ThirdName>
    <FullName>TestSecName TestName TestThirdName</FullName>
  </Persons>
</DBModel>
```

Если добавить нод и сохранить:

```
var asd = doc1.CreateElement("Location");
asd.InnerText = Text;
parent.AppendChild(asd);
doc1.Save(filePath1.Replace(".xml", "_new.xml"));
```

То получится:

```
  <Persons>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>TestName</Name>
    <SecondName>TestSecName</SecondName>
    <ThirdName>TestThirdName</ThirdName>
    <FullName>TestSecName TestName TestThirdName</FullName>
    <Location xmlns="">Text</Location>
  </Persons>
```

Соответственно `<Location xmlns="">`/// не читается

Comment: попробуйте `doc1.CreateElement("Location", "http://tempuri.org/DBModel.xsd")`

Comment: Работает, благодарю. Вынесите ответ, чтобы я мог его принять

Comment: или так `doc1.CreateElement("Location", doc1.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)`, чтобы пространство имен явно не указывать

Comment: @kmv да точно )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В корневом элементе указан нэймспейс `xmlns="http://tempuri.org/DBModel.xsd"`
Поэтому, при вызове `CreateElement` необходимо указывать этот неймспейс.
Т.к. это корневой неймспейс его можно получить напрямую из корня документа (`doc1.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI`)

```
var asd = doc1.CreateElement("Location", doc1.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
asd.InnerText = Text;
parent.AppendChild(asd);
doc1.Save(filePath1.Replace(".xml", "_new.xml"));
```

Comment: Неймспейс корневого элемента может не совпадать с неймспейсом родительского

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, ну, я как бы в курсе. ) я в разрезе заданного вопроса

Answer (score 5):

У Вас все элементы принадлежат пространству имен `http://tempuri.org/DBModel.xsd`. А новый элемент Вы создаете в пустом пространстве имен. Отсюда и результат

```
<Location xmlns="">Text</Location>
```

Вам нужно создавать новый элемент также в пространстве имен `http://tempuri.org/DBModel.xsd`. Для этого существует перегруженный метод

```
XmlDocument.CreateElement (String, String)
```

где второй аргумент позволяет задать требуемое пространство имен. Итого, Ваш код будет таким

```
var asd = doc1.CreateElement("Location", "http://tempuri.org/DBModel.xsd");
```

или таким

```
var prfx = (parent.Prefix.Length > 0) ? parent.Prefix + ":" : "";
var asd = doc1.CreateElement(prfx + "Location", parent.NamespaceURI);
```

Comment: На мой взгляд, ваши действия не очень красивы. Вы технически более грамотно повторяете то, что было сказано, почему было просто не отредактировать тот ответ? Мы же тут не устраиваем гонки в репутации ;-)

Comment: @FoggyFinder 1) На момент публикования ответа я других ответов не видел. 2) Мой ответ более общий и универсальный. 3) Если Вы считаете, что мой ответ нарушает правила сообщества, можете пометить его тревогой и привлечь внимание модератора